# How to create aws budget alarm for every account separately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am creating an aws budget alarm using terraform. I know how to create one alarm for specific account in aws.
I want to create a terraform code where I will be able to create for example 100 budget alarms for 100 accounts in aws.
I can't create one budget alarm for all accounts because I want to bill my expenses separately and if any of these accounts exceeds the budget I want to receive an email.

How to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

For this task, I agree with `@samtoddler` that AWS StackSets would solve the problem better than Terraform. But if you still want to go with Terraform, one approach would be creating a terraform module and use it in your target accounts.

I wrote this module if you need [Budget Alarms for Terraform](https://github.com/rribeiro1/terraform-aws-budget-alarms). It can also be integrated with Slack for receiving notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need setup to [terrform aws providers](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs) with cross-account [Delegate access across AWS accounts using IAM roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) IAM roles access for each account and then subsequently use them while creating the budget alerts.

```
provider "aws" {
  alias  = "myaccount"
  region = "eu-central-1"

  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/AdminRole"
  }

  allowed_account_ids = ["1234567890"]
}
```

And then eventually use them for various resources

```
resource "aws_budgets_budget" "cost" {
  provider = "aws.myaccount"
  # ...
  budget_type  = "COST"
  limit_amount = "100"
  limit_unit   = "USD"
}
```

`OR`

If you are using [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/) to centrally manage accounts.

You can use [AWS StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html) to create a codebuild job in the destination account with your terraform code which creates the alerts.

`Preferred` way because this will take care of creating the codebuild job as soon as the new account is available(`depending on your configure weather to do in the whole Organization or use Organization Units(OU).

Then you can use lambda in the `organizations master account` to invoke that codebuild job with custom params like the `budget` for that particular account. This too can be automated if we send back an event(`SNS`) from the destination account to master account and hook our lambda to the same.

If you are tagging your AWS accounts [Tagging AWS Organizations resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_tagging.html) you can have some information predefined somewhere in `DynamoDB` and use that in your lambda to invoke the corresponding codebuild job.

`OR`

Just create a `stackset` and with some cloudformation code like below and which triggers from the `organization master account` with the `budget` amount as param to the stack.

- whole Organization
- per Organization Unit(`OU`),
- per account.

```yaml
Resources:

  # note that changing some attributes on Budget resources will result in an error.
  # this unfortunately is a cloudformation error described here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/365
  # workaround is to delete the budget resource and then re-add it.
  Budget:
    Type: AWS::Budgets::Budget
    Properties:
      Budget:
        BudgetName: !Sub '${resourcePrefix}-budget-${AWSAccount.Alias}' # AWSAccount.Alias resolves to IAM Alias of current account
        BudgetLimit:
          Amount: !GetAtt AWSAccount.Tags.budget-alarm-threshold # Resolves to value of tag of current account
          Unit: USD
        TimeUnit: MONTHLY
        BudgetType: COST
      NotificationsWithSubscribers:
        - Notification:
            NotificationType: FORECASTED
            ComparisonOperator: GREATER_THAN
            Threshold: 1
          Subscribers:
            - SubscriptionType: SNS
              Address: !Ref BudgetAlarmTopic
            - SubscriptionType: EMAIL
              Address: olaf_conijn@hotmail.com
```